# I'd like to get a YouTube Reporting Sample Bulk Report

Tags: youtube-analytics-api, youtube-analytics

I'm using [YouTube Reporting API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/reporting/v1/reports/).

According to this API's feature, I must wait 2 days to get the result.
So I'd like to know data structures and contents in advance.
I appreciate if anyone has or know sample bulk reports.

Thanks

Comment: have you checked the documentation https://developers.google.com/youtube/reporting/v1/reports/

Comment: I just checked again, and I got about the content of results roughly.
I must wait for completion of creating report job.

Comment: @ShintaroSoyama, Are you having sample report now.. sharing will be helpful for us